# Extract a list of strings from a file, only from first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I wanted to extract a list of numbers (`string.txt`) from `masterFile.list`. `masterFile.list` is separated by `|` and contained more than one column. I am only interested with the line, where its first column contained number matched in the `string.txt` file.

string.txt:

```
3075
3078
3076
```

masterFile.list

```
3078    |       Auxenochlorella pyrenoidosa (H.Chick) Molinari & Calvo-Perez, 2015      |                   |       authority       |
3079    |       Auxenochlorella pyrenoidosa 3078    |               |       scientific name |
3076    |       Chlorella pyrenoidosa H.Chick, 1903     |               |       authority       |
3077    |       Chlorella vulgaris var. viridis Chodat, 1913    |               |       authority
487     |       ATCC 13077      |       ATCC 13077 <type strain>        |       type material   |
460     |       DSM 23076       |       DSM 23076 <type strain> |       type material   |
```

expected output:

```
3078    |       Auxenochlorella pyrenoidosa (H.Chick) Molinari & Calvo-Perez, 2015      |                       |       authority       |
3076    |       Chlorella pyrenoidosa H.Chick, 1903     |               |       authority       |
```

Most of the previous post I have found only allow the extraction of single string, and limit match to first column. Is it possible to extract more than one string at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` program:

```
awk -F' *|' 'NR==FNR{searchstr[$1]=1} NR>FNR && ($1 in searchstr) {print}' string.txt masterFile.list
```

As you can see, you provide both files as arguments to `awk`.

- While the first file is processed (indicated by `FNR`, the per-file line-counter, being equal to `NR`, the global line counter), we simply register all search strings (field nr. 1 of each line, since they are the only items)  in an array `searchstr` (however, in form of an *array index*, so the "value" is just a dummy value of `1`).
- When we come to the second file (`NR` is now greater than `FNR`), we check if the first column (`$1`) is contained *as an array index* in `searchstr`. If so, we print the entire line.

The idea behind this is that `awk` has a convenient syntax `string in array` which is true if `string` is in the list of array indices of `array`.

As noted by Ed Morton, you can "golf" this into

```
awk -F' *|' 'NR==FNR{searchstr[$1]; next} $1 in searchstr' string.txt masterFile.list
```

The `searchstr[$1]` call will define (but not fill) that array entry, and the `$1 in searchstr` *outside* of the rule block will - if evaluating to `true` - instruct `awk` to print the current line. The `next` instruction in the rule for processing `string.txt` will ensure that this part is only reached for `masterFile.list`

Note that I specified a full regular expression ( `*|`, i.e. any amount of space, followed by `|`) as field separator in order to ensure that the "first field" of `masterFile.list` really is only the number - specifying `-F'|'` would have meant that trailing space is included, too, and would have made the matching process more involved. If the "spaces" can actually also contain TABs, use `-F'[[:space:]]*|'` instead.

Comment: `'NR==FNR{searchstr[$1]; next} $1 in searchstr'` is all you need.

Comment: @EdMorton Huh, you are right!

Comment: FWIW it's usually just written as `'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a'` but a more meaningful array name certainly doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

multiple options as others have pointed.

```
for i in $(cat string.txt); do grep -E "(^$i)" masterFile.txt; done
```

Comment: Avoid `for i in $(cat file)`, instead use `while read i; do ...; done < file`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: Copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net to learn some of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
cat string.txt| while read -r str; do egrep "^$str *\|" masterFile.list;done
```

Comment: Copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net to learn some of the issues.