# select rows based on specific column values

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, paste

How can I select all rows in a text file based on different values of a particular column? The desired values are not in a specific interval.

A short example of what I expect is given below.

My data stored in a text file `input.txt`

```
1.0     21
2.5     23
4.0     21
6.5     45
9.0     30
16.5    46
2.0     78
1.0     20
1.6     19
2.5     25
4.0     40
5.2     16
6.5     25
9.0     47
10.0    14
16.5    60
18.5    65
20.0    57
.
.etc
```

I want to select rows based on 1st column having values 2.5,6.5,16.5,..., etc

So the output will look like this. I don't want to sort output numerically by 1st column.

```
2.5     23
6.5     45
16.5    46
2.5     25
6.5     25
16.5    60
```

I am looking for solutions in `awk` or `sed` or `paste`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply string the numbers together as an `awk` condition:

```
$ awk '$1==2.5 || $1==6.5 || $1==16.5' file
2.5     23
6.5     45
16.5    46
2.5     25
6.5     25
16.5    60
```

That can get really annoying if you have a long list, of course. Another option is to save the numbers you want in another file:

```
$ cat wantedNums
16.5
2.5 
6.5
```

And then use that to filter your input file:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} $1 in a' wantedNums file
2.5     23
6.5     45
16.5    46
2.5     25
6.5     25
16.5    60
```

Comment: my problem is  I have a lot of such desired values.

Comment: @terdon I have recently been [told by Ed Morton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608759/extract-a-list-of-strings-from-a-file-only-from-first-column/608763#comment1136195_608763) that `a[$1]` is sufficient to populate an array "with indices only".

Comment: @terdon ... which would actually make this question a duplicate ...

Comment: @AdminBee well I'll be... That's excellent, I had never realized it! Thanks! And yes, there are several dupes of this, I just never find them easily. Yours will do nicely.

Comment: @linux_lover if you have many desired values, use the second approach in my answer as explained in the answer.

Comment: @terdon Thanks you very much. I worked. Is there any way to 'skip' desired value or values if it's not in the 1st column and automatically select the next value and do the rest?

Comment: @linux_lover I don't understand, this only checks in the first column. It sounds like you're asking a different question now, so please post it separately so you can explain more clearly.

Comment: @terdon yes sure, I'll post it separately.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone for the help. I will delete this question shortly as it appears to be a duplicate of another existing question.

Comment: No, please don't delete! Duplicates are useful since they point others in the right direction.